# How to find the length of a string in MySql store procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

i am writing a query containing FIND_IN_SET and the where condition is as follows

```
WHERE 
    AND pmd.searchable =1
    AND FIND_IN_SET( categorie_heading,categoryheading) 
    AND FIND_IN_SET( categorie_discription,catdiscription) 
    AND FIND_IN_SET( Brand,categorybrand) 
    AND price
        BETWEEN minprice  
            AND maxprice  
GROUP BY p.prod_id;
```

i want all categoryheading value if the value is not set for categoryheading(if the value is null or empty string) but FIND_IN_SET obtains the value specified by categoryheading so i thought of obtaining the string length and if the length is greater than zero then concatenate the required where condition ...

Please help me to solve this, Please let me know if there is any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this function?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

CHAR_LENGTH(str)

Returns the length of the string str, measured in characters. A multi-byte character counts as a single character. This means that for a string containing five 2-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10, whereas CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.